# Process image request programmatically and return stream in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, image, http, sinatra

This idea is currently just on the drawing board, and I was first wondering whether it is possible, then how it could be done.

Say that an app in Sinatra has the following app file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8

require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do 
  "Hello World"
end

get '/' do 
  erb :index
end


get '/url_to_img.jpg'
  #parse url
  #process an image
  #stream the image back to the client as nothing have happened
end
```

Could the image request be intercepted, and how could an image file be returned wrapped in a HTTP respond.

Sorry, for the very crude question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is possible. All you need to do is to return the binary data in your Sinatra route, ensuring that you have the right MIME type for the file.

Here's an example that detects the image MIME, creates a thumbnail and returns the thumbnail to the browser:

```
get '/:filename' do |filename|
  redirect 404 unless File.readable?(filename)
  content_type detect_mime_type(filename)
  create_thumbnail filename
end
```

I'm using the following helpers:

```
require 'filemagic'
require 'rmagick'

def detect_mime_type(path)
  FileMagic.new(FileMagic::MAGIC_MIME)
  .file(path).gsub(/\n/,"").split(";").first
end

def create_thumbnail(path)
  Magick::Image.read(filename)
  .first.resize_to_fill(680, 500)
end
```

Of course, you should not serve files from your main website directory; this is for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and template code, I will try this out :)